# Angular v-accordion disabling collapse when clicked on a button inside v-pane-header

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accordion

I'm using angular v-accordion in project, there is a requriment to stop collapsing the accordion when only cliked on a button located inside a v-pane header.

this is the sample code.
And is have incuded a codepen link also.

```
<v-accordion control="accordionA">

    <v-pane  expanded="pane.isExpanded">
      <v-pane-header>
        <h5>{{ ::pane.header }}</h5>
        <button>Button</button>
      </v-pane-header>

      <v-pane-content>
        <p>{{ ::pane.content }}</p>
<v-pane-content>
</v-pane>
</v-accordion>
```

Codepen link  : [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNjRKZ)

Highly appreciate if anyone can help on this..
thank you in advance.

Cheers!.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ng-click to your button. The button will call a function that will switch some boolean flag to true:

```
$scope.stopCollapsing = false;
$scope.toggleCollapse = function(){
  $scope.stopCollapsing = true;
}
```

Then add to you collapseCallback an if statement:

```
   $scope.collapseCallback = function (index, id) {
    if($scope.stopCollapsing){
      $scope.accordionA.toggle(index);
    }
    console.log('collapse:', index, id);
  };
```

And that's it. and now you can switch stopCollapsing from everywhere to prevent collapsing.
This is your update codepen version:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrxEqQ